# Web References Error - Unable to import operation

Tags: web-services, asmx

I'm trying to setup a web reference from an MVC4 (.net 4.5) project to an older style ASMX web service.

I can browse the service without any issues and the wsdl disco stuff is all available as expected but when I try to actually reference the service I get the following error:

"Unable to import operation 'Login'. Member Diagram.Item of type Channel hides base class member Element.Item of type AbstractSchedule1. Use XmlElementAttribute or XmlAttributeAttribute to specify a new name.    "

I do not have control over this service at all so I have to work with what I have available but really not sure how to code around this or even if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Have you tried using "Add Service Reference"? It can be used on ASMX services as well.

Comment: Hi John, yes I've used every method from within VS and I've tried doing it outside of VS using just the command line tool, all throw up the same error ... I've logged a support call with the Web Service vendor to see what they come up with.  Thanks.